# Question on grammatically correct statement

Tags: sentence-choice

> Which amongst the following is grammatically correct?
>
> A) **Almost** nobody is interested **in** spending time **on** reading classical mechanics.
>   B) **Almost** nobody is interested **about** spending time **on** reading classical mechanics.
>   C) **Hardly** anybody is interested **in** spending time reading classical mechanics.
>   D) **Hardly** anybody is interested **in** spending time **in** reading classical mechanics.

Here, options (A) & (B) ruled out as the word '**almost**' is not used with negative words (i.e, **nobody**);
but, why can't answer be (**D**)? Any help please...

Comment: *Almost* can't be used with *nobody*? That's news to this educated native speaker... I mean, it's a little informal, but hardly beyond the pale... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=almost+nobody%2Chardly+anybody%2Calmost+noone%2Chardly+anyone&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calmost%20nobody%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chardly%20anybody%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calmost%20noone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chardly%20anyone%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Calmost%20nobody%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chardly%20anybody%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calmost%20noone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chardly%20anyone%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Sorry, that should have been https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=almost+nobody%2Chardly+anybody%2Calmost+no+one%2Chardly+anyone&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calmost%20nobody%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chardly%20anybody%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calmost%20no%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chardly%20anyone%3B%2Cc0

Comment: (B) is ruled out not by *Almost nobody*, but by the fact that we aren't interested ***about*** things but ***in*** things. And (A) is ruled out by the fact that we don't *spend time on ——ing*, but just *spend time ———ing*.

Comment: @PeterShor You mean it's incorrect to say *spend time on playing chess* ?

Comment: @SamBC Can you please explain what does *0.0000040%* signify in https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=almost+nobody%2Chardly+anybody%2Calmost+no+one%2Chardly+anyone&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calmost%20nobody%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chardly%20anybody%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calmost%20no%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chardly%20anyone%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Calmost%20nobody%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Chardly%20anybody%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calmost%20no%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chardly%20anyone%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Suresh: that's the only reason I can think of for ruling (A) out. It's certainly a lot less common than saying *spend time playing chess* — one Google hit versus eighty hits.

Comment: Don't worry about the specific numbers in ngram results. It's most useful for relative stuff.

Comment: @PeterShor: "spend time on *gerund-participle*" might not be as common as leaving the "on" out, but it's still normal in my experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting aside the correctness or otherwise of ruling out A&B, D wouldn't be natural simply because we don't talk about spending time *in* reading anything. You either don't use any preposition, or you use *on*.